# wxPython: How to Show status/progress window and update the progress from another python code?

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I have a regular python app (not wx) , and i want to add a wxStatusWindow (Guage Class) in order to show the progress in my App.
There are many examples in web for wxGuage /Status windows but in all examples the progress is handled within the wxFrame.

How can i call the statusWIndow from my python code while the python code is running ?

I did some reading...is it running on separate thread??

I will appreciate an example...how can i do that?

alternatively..I though of just opening a wxDialog from my app and showing info about the progress (and than closing it and raising another wxDialog with new info)...but again..
I need the message to be displayed and in parallel the code in my app to continue running..and than to be able to close the message box from my python app

any Idea's? 
code examples?

10x
Yodash

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have some examples to share that demonstrate a specific problem you're running in to?

Comment: Look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56532866/how-to-load-a-heavy-model-when-using-mvc-design-pattern/56541556#56541556)

Comment: Turn your question around and control the `other` procesing from the `wx` GUI using threading.