# how to stabilize the speed of my wx.Gauge

Tags: python-3.5, wxpython

the speed of my gauge varies according to the instructions of the thread that is running with it. when the instructions are simple my gauge goes very fast but when it is necessary to read a file my gauge is very slow. I want to stabilize it at the same pace.
Even worse when you have to extract text from an image file the gauge crashes. and plant the GUI

```
wx.Gauge(self, -1, 20, pos=(150, 300), size=(250, 25), style = wx.GA_HORIZONTAL)
```

I have already changed `Range` with more value (`now Range=20`) but nothing

Comment: please post a runnable example

Comment: @user2682863 below the code of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gauge runs with a Thread that reads the file. When you have to read a Txt file the gauge goes fast but when you have to read the Docx the gauge slows down worse when you have to read the texts of an image the gauge crashes the GUI. I want to avoid my GUI crashes. If possible stabilize the speed of the gauge.

```
import time
import datetime
class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer)
        self.gspeed = 20
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.timer.Start(self.gspeed)

        self.star = True
        self.start_time = time.time()

        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):

        pnl = wx.Panel(self)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)


        self.btn2 = wx.Button(pnl, wx.ID_STOP)
        self.text = wx.StaticText(pnl)
        self.count = wx.StaticText(pnl)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStop, self.btn2)
        self.gauge = wx.Gauge(pnl,20, size=(250, -1), style = wx.GA_HORIZONTAL)
        hbox1.Add(self.gauge, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)

        hbox2.Add(self.btn2, proportion=1)
        hbox3.Add(self.text, proportion=1, flag=wx.RIGHT, border=50)
        hbox3.Add(self.count, proportion=1)

        vbox.Add((0, 30))

        vbox.Add(hbox1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)

        vbox.Add((0, 20))

        vbox.Add(hbox2, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        vbox.Add(hbox3, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)

        pnl.SetSizer(vbox)

        self.SetTitle('Gauge')
        self.Centre()


    def OnStop(self, e):

        self.timer.Stop()
        self.text.SetLabel('Task Interrupted')

    def OnTimer(self, e):

        self.gauge.Pulse()
        self.SetTimeLabel()

    def get_elapsed_time(self):
        val = round(time.time() - self.start_time, 1)
        hours = val/3600
        minutes = (val%3600)/60
        seconds = val%60
        strs = ("%lu:%02lu:%02lu")%(hours, minutes, seconds)

        return strs

    def SetTimeLabel(self):

        self.text.SetLabel("{elapsed} seconds elapsed".format(elapsed=self.get_elapsed_time()))


def main():

    app = wx.App()
    ex = Example(None)
    ex.Show()
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: See the 2nd answer (using events) for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56532866/how-to-load-a-heavy-model-when-using-mvc-design-pattern/56548071#56548071

Comment: After a careful study of my project I realized that my GUI crash when the application works in the background and that I try to open another application. I dont know what can be the cause of this crash  `Python3.5.2` and `4.0.6 msw (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.0.5`

Comment: You would have to give a precise description of your setup, a specific application example, perhaps a file that everyone can access, your OS and define `crash`. Hopefully someone with the same setup can then replicate the error when running  your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your example didn't include anything that showed how you were reading the files, but I'll assume based on the description of your problem that they were called from the main thread. There are many [examples](https://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks) of how and why you need to run blocking functions from another thread to keep the UI responsive. If you run a function from the main thread it blocks the event loop, meaning none of your normal events (like EVT_TIMER) get called until the function finishes. Here is your example with a simulated long running task in its own thread.

```
import time
import datetime
import wx
import threading


class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer)
        self.gspeed = 20
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.timer.Start(self.gspeed)

        self.star = True
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.thread = None

        self.InitUI()
        self.start_long_running_task()


    def start_long_running_task(self):
        """
        :return: starts the long running task in its own thread to keep the UI responsive
        :rtype:
        """
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.long_running_task)
        self.thread.start()

    def long_running_task(self):
        """
        :return:  simulated long running task
        :rtype:
        """
        print("long running task has started")
        # checks if the window has been closed and if the timer is still running
        while bool(self) and self.timer.IsRunning():
            # do something
            time.sleep(1)
        # the timer was stopped or the window was closed
        print("long running task is exiting")

    def InitUI(self):
        pnl = wx.Panel(self)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.btn2 = wx.Button(pnl, wx.ID_STOP)
        self.text = wx.StaticText(pnl)
        self.count = wx.StaticText(pnl)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStop, self.btn2)
        self.gauge = wx.Gauge(pnl, 20, size=(250, -1), style=wx.GA_HORIZONTAL)
        hbox1.Add(self.gauge, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)

        hbox2.Add(self.btn2, proportion=1)
        hbox3.Add(self.text, proportion=1, flag=wx.RIGHT, border=50)
        hbox3.Add(self.count, proportion=1)

        vbox.Add((0, 30))

        vbox.Add(hbox1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)

        vbox.Add((0, 20))

        vbox.Add(hbox2, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        vbox.Add(hbox3, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)

        pnl.SetSizer(vbox)

        self.SetTitle('Gauge')
        self.Centre()

    def OnStop(self, e):
        self.timer.Stop()
        self.text.SetLabel('Task Interrupted')

    def OnTimer(self, e):
        self.gauge.Pulse()
        self.SetTimeLabel()

    def get_elapsed_time(self):
        val = round(time.time() - self.start_time, 1)
        hours = val / 3600
        minutes = (val % 3600) / 60
        seconds = val % 60
        strs = ("%lu:%02lu:%02lu") % (hours, minutes, seconds)

        return strs

    def SetTimeLabel(self):
        self.text.SetLabel("{elapsed} seconds elapsed".format(elapsed=self.get_elapsed_time()))


def main():
    app = wx.App()
    ex = Example(None)
    ex.Show()
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I tried this and it still does not work. In fact during the execution of my application if I open another application, the GUI of my application (the one I develop) crashes but the thread gives me the results normally

Comment: @LandryEngolo it's hard to diagnose without seeing the actual code- My best guess would be that you're trying to start or stop the timer from the `long_running_task` thread, but that's just a guess. Any UI manipulation should come from the main thread

Answer (score 1):

This is an example based on the code I recommended in my comment.
The Start/Stop button will start or stop the file loading.
The `Other task` button simply prints the contents of the textctrl boxes as proof that the program is not locked by the file loading thread.

```
import wx
import time
from threading import Thread
import wx.lib.newevent
progress_event, EVT_PROGRESS_EVENT = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()
load_status=["File Loading","File Loaded","Cancelled"]

class Model(Thread):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stopthread = 0
        self.target = parent
        #self.start()

    def run(self):
        line_counter = 0
        with open('../xxx.html', 'r') as f:
            while not self.stopthread:
                    line = f.readline()
                    if not line:
                        break
                    line_counter += 1
                    print(line_counter)
                    if self.stopthread:
                        break
                    time.sleep(0.05)
                    evt = progress_event(count=line_counter, status=self.stopthread)
                    wx.PostEvent(self.target, evt)
            if self.stopthread == 0:
                self.stopthread = 1
        evt = progress_event(count=line_counter, status=self.stopthread)
        wx.PostEvent(self.target, evt)

    def terminate(self):
        self.stopthread = 2

class View(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(View, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(400, 400))
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.fgs = wx.FlexGridSizer(6, 2, 10, 25)
        id = wx.StaticText(self, label="ID:")
        firstName = wx.StaticText(self, label="First name:")
        lastName = wx.StaticText(self, label="Last name:")
        self.id = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        self.firstName = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        self.lastName = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        self.stop = wx.Button(self, -1, "Start")
        self.other = wx.Button(self, -1, "Other task")

        self.fgs.AddMany([id, (self.id, 1, wx.EXPAND),
                         firstName, (self.firstName, 1, wx.EXPAND),
                         lastName, (self.lastName, 1, wx.EXPAND),
                         (self.stop,1,wx.EXPAND),
                         (self.other,1,wx.EXPAND)])

        self.vbox.Add(self.fgs, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND,border=15)
        #Bind to the progress event issued by the thread
        self.Bind(EVT_PROGRESS_EVENT, self.OnProgress)
        #Bind to Stop button
        self.stop.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStartStop)
        #Bind to Other task button
        self.other.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOther)
        #Bind to Exit on frame close
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnExit)
        self.SetSizer(self.vbox)
        self.Layout()

        self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar(2)
        self.text = wx.StaticText(self.statusbar,-1,("No File loaded"))
        self.progress = wx.Gauge(self.statusbar, range=20)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.text, 0, wx.ALIGN_TOP|wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.progress, 1, wx.ALIGN_TOP|wx.ALL, 5)
        self.statusbar.SetSizer(sizer)
        #wx.BeginBusyCursor()
        self.loadthread = Model(self)


    def OnProgress(self, event):
        self.text.SetLabel(load_status[event.status])
        #self.progress.SetValue(event.count)
        #or for indeterminate progress
        self.progress.Pulse()
        if event.status != 0:
            wx.EndBusyCursor()
            self.Update()
            time.sleep(1)
            #self.statusbar.Hide()
            #Re-set thread in case it needs to be restarted
            self.loadthread = Model(self)
            self.stop.SetLabel("Start")
            self.progress.SetValue(0)
            self.text.SetLabel("")

    def OnStartStop(self, event):
        if self.loadthread.isAlive():
            self.loadthread.terminate() # Shutdown the thread
            self.loadthread.join() # Wait for it to finish
            #Re-set thread in case it needs to be restarted
            self.loadthread = Model(self)
            self.stop.SetLabel("Start")
            self.progress.SetValue(0)
            self.text.SetLabel("")
        else:
            wx.BeginBusyCursor()
            self.loadthread.start()
            self.stop.SetLabel("Stop")

    def OnExit(self, event):
        if self.loadthread.isAlive():
            self.loadthread.terminate() # Shutdown the thread
            self.loadthread.join() # Wait for it to finish
        self.Destroy()

    def OnOther(self, event):
        print("Other Task")
        print(self.id.GetValue())
        print(self.firstName.GetValue())
        print(self.lastName.GetValue())

class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
        self.view = View(None, title='Test')
        self.view.Show()

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    controller = Controller()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]